# VPN connection: Not resolving internal network hostnames

Tags: vpn, nat, hostname, internal-dns, pptp

I have set up a PPTP VPN connection where I can connect to my company network, but I cannot access my shares via file server's hostname.

The OS of the VPN Client is Windows 10 and I use the built-in setup for the connection.

I have tried 3 things:

- making a VPN server to my router with my Main DHCP Pool,
- making a VPN server to my router with Guest DHCP Pool and,
- setting up VPN connection to Windows File Server.

In all scenarios, I can connect but not resolve the File Server hostname, so I would use the shares without mounting them with the IP address.

I have been searching through the Internet a theory/solution, but I am a bit confused.

Should I set up a DNS server or the problem is to my VPN Client? Are there some settings for my VPN Client or I have forgotten something in my configuration of the VPN Server? Is it possible NAT causing this problem?

I am interested in the second scenario, but any advice, method or link with theory and examples would be appreciated.

Comment: What DNS server are you using when connected to the VPN? Is it your internal DNS?

Comment: I do not have DNS server. I am using 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 for my network.

While I was configuring the VPN, I did not set any DNS settings. Should I look for these and try a setup with 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 too?

Comment: Why do you expect Google's DNS servers to be able to resolve hostnames from your private network?

Comment: The thing is I do not expect something like that. It was something like a reassuring question, as I am new to the field. But, I do not know how my client PC resolves the hostnames when I am in the company and not when I am using the VPN. I am missing something in the configuration chain and I do not know how to search it. I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: You can use the `dig` and `nslookup` commands to see what DNS server is returning the answer to your internal queries.

Comment: Thanks, your previous comments led me to clarify some things:

- I never mentioned that there is no domain. It is a small business with a file server and some PC hosts. So. . .
- `nslookup` gave me nothing. But, the answer was from my router address.
- I have found in my router vpn-profile settings such as **DNS Server** & **WINS Server**. I have tried my router address in both fields and it advertised them to the client PC but no results.

Comment: Are the PCs and fileserver on a Windows homegroup?

Comment: No, nothing at all. I have checked in DHCP server's settings that internal network's pool has router's IP as a DNS record, so maybe that is how it resolves hostnames when I am at work. But, I can't think of a way to use it to my VPN link. Thank you for your concern.